# Recursive pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I was talking to someone who was new to low level languages, and manual memory management today and doing my best to explain pointers.

He then came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int v = 0;
    void* vp = &v;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("vp: %p, &vp: %p\n", vp, &vp);
        vp = &vp;
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
vp: 0xbfd29bf8, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
vp: 0xbfd29bf4, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
```

Which makes no sense to him as vp should != &vp. I'm ashamed to say that I don't know what's going on here.. so, what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have this line in code

```
    vp = &vp;
```

it's no surprise that `vp == &vp`...

In the first iteration, it is as you (and he) expect.

Comment: Hmn, I didn't realize &vp decayed to vp? Why doesn't it do so in the printf?

Comment: @KimSun-wu: It doesn't decay.

Comment: `&vp` does not decay to `vp`. What that assignment does is it stores the address of `vp` in `vp` (the RAM cell belonging to `vp`). So, at address `0xbfd29bf4` you have the value `0xbfd29bf4`.

Comment: Ah. Doh. Obviously, this isn't what he was asking, he just wrote the code wrong, and I was too stupid to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Once this code has run:

```
vp = &vp;
```

the *pointer variable* now indeed stores address of itself. Note that this only happens after the initial loop iteration - the first line output is

```
vp: 0xbfd29bf8, &vp: 0xbfd29bf4
```

and values are not the same yet because the assignment above has not yet been done.

Answer (score 1):

> Which makes no sense to him as vp should != &vp.

Why shouldn't it, after you've made that assignment?

If it helps, try thinking of every variable as occupying a numbered location in memory, and a pointer as holding one of those numbered memory location. Why shouldn't a void pointer be able to store a value that happens to identify its own location?

Comment: What he was actually asking was if he could recursively get pointers to the original pointer (i.e, void****..). I had a brain fart and assumed that's what the above code was doing, my bad.