# pointer of pointer of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I was dabbling with c pointers and couldn't explain the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int i = -3; 
    int *ptr;
    int **ptr2;
    int ***ptr3;
    ptr = &i; 
    ptr2 = &ptr;
    ptr3 = &ptr2;
    printf("ptr = %p\n",(void *)ptr);
    printf("&ptr = %p\n",(void *)&ptr);
    printAddr(&ptr);
    printAddr2(&ptr2);
    printAddr3(&ptr3);
    return 0;
}

void printAddr(int **num)
{
    printf("address of int ** = %p\n", (void *)&num);
}

void printAddr2(int ***num)
{
    printf("address of int *** = %p\n", (void *)&num);
}
void printAddr3(int ****num)
{
    printf("address of int **** = %p\n", (void *)&num);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
ptr = 0xbf9d64a0 
&ptr = 0xbf9d64a4
address of int ** = 0xbf9d6490
address of int *** = 0xbf9d6490
address of int **** = 0xbf9d6490
```

My doubt is why should address `(address(int)) == address(address(address(int)))` ?

Thanks a lot for the clarification.

I found that this question is relevant:

[Recursive pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940252/recursive-pointers)

But the author is explicitly assigning them to be equal.

Comment: I guess that's related to compiler optimization... what gets output when you switch optimization off completely? The same?

Comment: btw **** are general's stars, smell of bad design, rather don't use them :)

Comment: Your code is broken as is. Assignment `ptr3 = &ptr2` is a constraint violation, i.e. an error. The right-hand side is `int ***` while the left-hand side is `int **`. Don't waste your time trying to analyze broken code accepted by compilers with overly loose error checking. First, learn how to make your compiler detect all errors. The error messages alone will explain a lot.

Comment: thanks Andrey, I have missed one * while writing the question.

Comment: If you ever have a type that is more than doubly-indirect (i.e. more than Type**, i.e. Type*** or Type**** etc), then You're Doing It Wrong (TM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void printAddr(int **num)
{
   printf("address of int ** = %p\n",(void *)&num);
}
```

That prints out the address of the copy of the passed-in value that the function received. These will likely be all allocated in the same place on the stack, since all these functions take only one argument, and no allocations occur between the calls.

If you want to see the addresses of the pointers in `main`, you should either print them directly in `main` or have a function

```
void printAddress(void* p) {
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

and call that with

```
printAddress(&ptr3);
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't get the idea for the function.

Comment: @kmad There's no deeper point for the function, I just added it because you had functions for printing the different pointer types.

Comment: @DanielFischer: My idea behind writing that piece of code was getting the address of pointer to a pointer .... and see what was happening.
Your printAddress function  helps in what I was trying to do and more: Print the address of any given variable.

Comment: Well, you can also directly call `printf("%p\n", (void*)&variable);`, so all that function would really buy you is saving a little typing if you give it a shorter name.